# html ordered list with bangla numeric values

Tags: html, html-lists

I want to start ordered list with bangla numeric values like the following:

```
১। আম 
২। জাম 
৩। কাঁঠাল 
৪। লিচু
```

Can anyone please help me with the solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to style the list in css. Use:

```
ol {
    list-style-type: bengali;
}
```

And it will make the numbers bengali.